# How can I include special characters (or html content) in sqlite3 database with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, sqlite

I am having some issues with PHP, sqlite3 and HTML.

What I want is a modal in HTML, that gets its content (header, body, footer) from a sqlite3 database. To access the database I use PHP. The user can then edit the content in the modal and the updated text gets send to the database.

Now this works for plain text (e.g. 'Hello world'). But it fails as soon as I include special characters (e.g. < > &). There is no error message on the console, so I don't really know what to fix. I tried SQLite3::escapeString but that did not change anything.

As a potential improvement I would also be ok with saving the complete html body into the sqlite3 database, instead of only the innerHTML, then I could do some nicer layouts.

I attach some code that I hope adds clarity below. For simplicity I do not include the header and footer part as it is the same as the body part.

This is the HTML code for the modal:

```
    <!-- Body content -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <input id="editBtn" type="button" , class="editBtn", value="edit" onclick="editFunction();" />
      <p id="modal-body-id"></p>
    </div>
```

This is the javascript that edits the content

```
function editFunction() {
  var editables_body   = document.querySelectorAll('#modal-body-id');

  if (!editables_body[0].isContentEditable) {
    editables_body[0].contentEditable = 'true';
  } else {
    // Disable Editing
    editables_body[0].contentEditable = 'false';
    // Save the data to database
    for (var i = 0; i < editables_body.length; i++) {
      // console.log(editables_body[0].innerHTML)
      sendData(modal_id)
    }
  }
```

Javascript to send the data to the database

```
function sendData(id){
  var body = document.getElementById("modal-body-id").innerHTML;

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "send2db.php");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("id="+id+"&header="+header+"&body="+body+"&footer="+footer);
}
```

Javascript to read the data from the database

```
function get_body(id) {
  var body = document.getElementById("modal-body-id");
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "get_from_db.php");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("id="+id+"&type=body");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      // body.innerHTML = this.responseText;
      body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    } else {
      body.innerHTML = "Loading...";
    };
  }
}
```

And finally the php scripts to send and read the database

send2db.php

```
<?php

// Database name
$database_name = "description.db";

// Database Connection
$db = new SQLite3($database_name);


// Get information
$id = $_POST['id'];
$header = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST["header"]);
$body   = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST["body"]);
$footer = SQLite3::escapeString($_POST["footer"]);

// Create Table of file descriptions into Database if not exists
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_desc(id TEXT, header TEXT, body TEXT, footer TEXT)");

$res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM file_desc WHERE id = '$id' ");
$row = $res->fetchArray();

$db->exec("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_id ON file_desc (id)");
$db->exec("REPLACE INTO file_desc (id, header, body, footer) VALUES('$id', '$header', '$body', '$footer') ");
// $db->exec("REPLACE INTO file_desc (id, '$type') VALUES('$id', '$body') ");

?>
```

get_from_db.php

```
<?php

  // Database name
  $database_name = "description.db";

  // Database Connection
  $db = new SQLite3($database_name);

  // Create empty database if none exists
  $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_desc(id TEXT, header TEXT, body TEXT, footer TEXT)");

  // Get information
  $id = $_POST['id'];

  // Get information
  $type = $_POST['type'];

  $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM file_desc WHERE id = '$id' ");


  while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
      echo "{$row[$type]} \n";
  }

  // $row = $res->fetchArray();
  // return "{$row['body']}";

?>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem.
I encode the data package to be send using `encodeURIComponent`.
I attach the same functions I mentioned above in their new working version.

It is a lengthy answer but I hope someone with a similar problem finds it helpful.

javascript to edit content of the modal:

```
// Edit content of modal
function editFunction() {    
  // Get editables
  var editables_body   = document.querySelectorAll('#modal-body-id');

  // Edit body
  if (!editables_body[0].isContentEditable) {
    editables_body[0].contentEditable = 'true';
  } else {
    // Disable Editing
    editables_body[0].contentEditable = 'false';
    sendData(modal_id);
  }
};
```

The javascript to send to the database. This contains the new function to encode the data:

```
function sendData(id){

  //Body
  var body = document.getElementById("modal-body-id"); // Get the body
  body.innerHTML = htmlEncode(body.innerHTML);        // Encode HTML characters
  body = encodeURIComponent(String(body.outerHTML));  //Encode for sending to database   

  // Open a new request
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "send2db.php");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  // Send the request to the php script that handles the database
  xmlhttp.send("id="+id+"&body="+body);
};
```

javascript to read from the database. This contains the new function to decode the data.

```
function get_body(id) {
  var body = document.getElementById("modal-body-id");
  var bodyDiv = body.parentNode;
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var response;
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "get_from_db.php");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send("id="+id+"&type=body");

  // Create an empty paragraph element
  // without an ID, any attributes, or any content
  var newBody = document.createElement("p");

  // Request from database
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
      response = htmlDecode(decodeURIComponent(xmlhttp.response));

      // Fill the new body with the response from the database
      newBody.innerHTML = response.innerText;
      newBody.id = 'modal-body-id';

      // Replace body with new body from the database
      bodyDiv.replaceChild(newBody,body)
    };
  }
}
```

The php scripts to send and read from the data base:

```
<?php

// Database name
$database_name = "description.db";

// Database Connection
$db = new SQLite3($database_name);

// Get information
$id = $_POST['id'];
$header = ($_POST["header"]);
$body   = ($_POST['body']);
$footer = ($_POST["footer"]);

// Create Table of file descriptions into Database if not exists
$db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_desc(id TEXT, header BLOB, body BLOB, footer BLOB)");

// Send to database
$db->exec("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS unique_id ON file_desc (id)");
$db->exec("REPLACE INTO file_desc (id, header, body, footer) VALUES('$id', '$header', '$body', '$footer') ");

?>



<?php

  // Database name
  $database_name = "description.db";

  // Database Connection
  $db = new SQLite3($database_name);

  // Create empty database if none exists
  $db->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file_desc(id TEXT, header TEXT, body TEXT, footer TEXT)");

  // Get information
  $id = $_POST['id'];

  // Get information
  $type = $_POST['type'];

  // Request from database
  $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM file_desc WHERE id = '$id' ");

  // Read from database
  while ($row = $res->fetchArray()) {
      // echo "{$row[$type]} \n";
      echo $row[$type];
  }

?>
```

And finally the two new functions that help en/decoding the content so it can be send to the database and read from the database:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('p');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e
}

function htmlEncode(input){
  var e = input.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
  return e
}
```